# Android Tab Bar Controller (Fragment or Action Bar or TabHost)

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments

I've been slowly porting my iOS App to Android so I can take my time and make sure that it functions correctly and I'm now at the part where I need to create a TabBarController like environment. I've been searching for days and have come across numerous examples but with each example there's a problem.

First, most examples refer to using a TabActivity, which when I just checked is deprecated and can't be used. The one's that don't use TabActivity either use Fragments (sometimes with an Action Bar) or a Tab Host. It looks like Fragments is the way to go, but then how to you support older devices (from the Android website over 50% of there users are still on API 10).

Basically what I need to set up is a Tabbed environment that will let each tab load a new Activity, and then each of those Activities will have their own navigation based hierarchy as well so I'm trying to see what is the best option to pursue and if anyone has seen some examples that can help.

I've found 4 tutorials so far that have fragments and different activities for each Tab, so I'm going to look into those now but just wanted to see if any other developers that have already come across and issue like this did to work with the compatibility issues with older devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Fragments all the way down to API 4 using the [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html).  I'd use a single Activity with multiple Fragments in ActionBar tabs, though you might need to do it with TabHost to support lower APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that's the one thing that I'm struggling with for Android is trying to find support for the lower API's since they are still a huge portion of users. I'll look into a Fragment with TabHost and see if that works for what I need.

Comment: if you are looking for ActionBar tabs in earlier API versions, use ActionBarSherlock. it ports the whole ActionBar functionality back to API 8. there are < 5% of users using API versions before 8.

Comment: @toadzky It actually works all the way down to 7. (0.5% of people are on APIs 1-6.)

Comment: gotcha. i refuse to support past 8 and i wouldn't even support that but my boss is making me. i watch every month as the number of people using 7 dwindles

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer since what Ralgha provided as well as toadzky's comment on ActionBarSherlock have got me going down the right path. I've got an actionbar setup now and it looks like Fragments is the best way to go as far as well for the navigation setup but this answers my initial question.